# ASP Xml Multiple Looping

Tags: xml, asp-classic

How would I go about looping through XML in order to populate an image?

I can loop through individual elements and it works, as shown below, but I want to access other elements from the same loop.

```
<%
    Dim xml, thumbnail, content, description, player, entry, title, list
    Set xml = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.FreeThreadedDOMDocument")
    xml.async = False
    xml.SetProperty "ServerHTTPRequest", True
    xml.Load("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/Shuggy23/favorites?orderby=updated&max-results=15")

    Set entry = xml.getElementsByTagName("entry")
    Set thumbnail = xml.getElementsByTagName("media:thumbnail")
    Set content = xml.getElementsByTagName("media:content")
    Set description = xml.getElementsByTagName("media:description")
    Set player = xml.getElementsByTagName("media:player")
    Set title = xml.getElementsByTagName("media:title")

    For Each xmlItem In thumbnail
        Response.Write xmlItem.getAttribute("url") & "<br />"
    Next

%>
```

I want to get values from other elements like title and player, but I have to use individual loops to get it to work.  Is there any way to get them in the same loop or at the same time?

Thank you

Douglas

Answer (score 0):

You can use XPATH inside Classic ASP

```
Dim xml, thumbnail, content, description, player, entry, title, list
Set xml = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.FreeThreadedDOMDocument")
xml.async = False
xml.SetProperty "ServerHTTPRequest", True
xml.Load("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/Shuggy23/favorites?orderby=updated&max-results=15")

set media_player = xml.selectNodes("feed[0]/entry[0]/media:group[0]/media:player[0]/@url")
if media_player.length > 0 then
    response.Write(media_player(0).Text)
else
    response.Write("not found")
end if
```

Here are a few examples that help with the basics of xpath: http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_examples.asp

Comment: Note that by default the selection language is XSL Pattern not XPath.  Whilst XPath is more powerful for some simple scenarios it can be more trouble than its worth.

Answer (score 0):

Well you'll want to avoid using the `getElementsByTagName` method, there just no good way to access structured info using that method.

Sounds to like you first want to enumerate the entries in the feed:-

```
 For Each entry In xml.selectNodes("feed/entry")
   ''# Do stuff with an entry.
 Next
```

Now for each entry you want to get the title and the player url and I'll assume you actually only want one of the many possible thumbnail URLs.

```
 For Each entry In xml.selectNodes("feed/entry")

     Response.Write "Title: " & Server.HTMLEncode(entry.selectSingleNode("title").Text) & "<br />"
     Response.Write "Player URL: " & Server.HTMLEncode(entry.selectSingleNode("media:group/media:player/@url).Text) & "<br />"
     Response.Write "Thumbnail URL : " & Server.HTMLEncode(entity.selectSingleNode("media:group/media:thumbnail/@url").Text) & "<br />"

     Response.Write "<br />"
 Next
```